# how to hide empty label in react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using react-bootstrap-typeahead module in one of my application. This is working fine, except in one case.

I'm not able to submit the form if there are no results. In this case, I'm getting a disabled option with *No matches found*.

[image]

I used the prop emptyLabel="", which gives me a result as shown below
[image]

In both cases, when I press ESC key, this option disappears and then, I'm able to submit my form.

the desired result is to get rid of this option. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
<form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
  <Typeahead
    labelKey="name"
    flip={true}
    dropup={true}
    autoFocus={true}
    options={this.state.options}
    ref={(typeahead) => this.typeahead = typeahead}
    id="qbox"
    placeholder="Type your queries here..."
    onInputChange={this.updateText}
    onBlur={(e) => this.updateText(e.target.value, e)}
    onChange={this.valueChanged}
    maxResults={5}
    minLength={5}
  />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details, like share some code snippet where you are facing issue.

Comment: @MonikaMangal edited question to include code.

Comment: @JacobNelson What version are you using?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the version. But from package.json, I got this number 4.0.0-alpha.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Hiding the menu

You'll need to add your own logic for when to render the menu, as falsy values for `emptyLabel` no longer hide the menu in v4. From the [migration docs](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/4.0/docs/Upgrading.md#falsy-emptylabel-no-longer-hides-the-menu-when-there-are-no-results):

> This behavior was a legacy workaround introduced before `renderMenu` could return `null`. That is no longer the case and renderMenu should now be used to achieve the behavior

You can hide the menu when there are no results by passing the following to `renderMenu`:

```
<Typeahead
  ...
  renderMenu={(results, menuProps) => {
    // Hide the menu when there are no results.
    if (!results.length) {
      return null;
    }
    return <TypeaheadMenu {...menuProps} options={results} />;
  }}
/>
```

#### Submitting the form

The typeahead blocks form submission when the menu is open to prevent inadvertent submissions. You can get around this by adding the following:

```
<Typeahead
  ...
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    // Submit the form when the user hits enter.
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.form.submit();
    }
  }}
/>
```

#### Putting it all together

```
<form ref={(form) => this.form = form}>
  <Typeahead
    id="rbt-example"
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
      // Submit the form when the user hits enter.
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.form.submit();
      }
    }}
    options={options}
    placeholder="Type your queries here..."
    renderMenu={(results, menuProps) => {
      // Hide the menu when there are no results.
      if (!results.length) {
        return null;
      }
      return <TypeaheadMenu {...menuProps} options={results} />;
    }}
  />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-typeahead-rtb1s

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Let me try this solution.

Comment: Hi Eric, I tried this solution, but getting following error. `Error: One or more options does not have a valid label string. Check the labelKey prop to ensure that it matches the correct option key and provides a string for filtering and display.` Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Hi Eric, an update: adding  `labelKey="name"` to `TypeaheadMenu` resolved the above said error. However, while hitting ENTER key, the form is not getting submitted. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Hi Eric, after making this change, I ended up following error, `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop search is marked as required in Highlighter, but its value is undefined. in Highlighter (created by TypeaheadMenu)`

Comment: @JacobNelson: Updated answer with additional code and a live example.

Comment: Hi Eric. Thank you. The problem got resolved with the solution you suggested and by downgrading the module to 3.4.5. However, there is an unexpected result, for which I raised another question. Could you please take a look at that and help me achieve the expected result. here is the link to that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922191/form-submit-callback-not-getting-invoked