# form.submit callback not getting invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the react-bootstrap-typeahead module in one of my application. This is working fine, except in one case.

I'm not able to submit the form by pressing the ENTER key if there are no results.

ie; 
if there are **suggestions** provided by react-bootstrap-typeahead, I'm able to select one of the options and submit the form. In this case, able to invoke the callback onSubmit.

if there are **no suggestions** provided by react-bootstrap-typeahead, not able to submit the form.

If I submit the form using form.submit() method onKeyDown event, the form will be submitted, however, the page gets refreshed instead of invoking callback, which results in complete out of my control result.

The desired result: I should be able to invoke onSubmit callback even if there is no suggestion provided by if there are suggestions provided by react-bootstrap-typeahead.

Here is my code.

```
<form ref={(form) => this.form = form} onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
  <Typeahead
    id="rbt-example"
    dropup={true}
    ref={(typeahead) => this.typeahead = typeahead}
    onChange={this.valueChanged}
    onInputChange={this.updateQuery}
    onBlur={(e) => this.updateQuery(e.target.value, e)}
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
      // Submit the form when the user hits enter.
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.form.submit();
      }
    }}
    options={options}
    placeholder="Type your queries here..."
    renderMenu={(results, menuProps) => {
      // Hide the menu when there are no results.
      if (!results.length) {
        return null;
      }
      return <TypeaheadMenu {...menuProps} options={results} />;
    }}
  />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you noticed the code in my question, I'm handling multiple events. Especially `onChange` and `onKeyDown`.

Couple of things we need to understand about `react-bootstrap-typeahead` is

1. `onChange`, react-bootstrap-typeahead will pass the selected object to callback whereas `onKeyDown` react-bootstrap-typeahead will pass the event, from which, I will get the value using `event.target.value`
2. `onChange` will be triggered only after `onKeyDown`. therefore, if we want to do some operation based on the selected object and that value to be used in `onKeyDown` callback will not work.

To overcome this situation, I used `setTimeout` also removed form element.
so my solution simply becomes

```
<Typeahead
    id="rbt-example"
    dropup={true}
    ref={(typeahead) => this.typeahead = typeahead}
    onChange={this.valueChanged}
    onInputChange={this.updateQuery}
    onBlur={(e) => this.updateQuery(e.target.value, e)}
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
      // Submit the form when the user hits enter.
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          if (this.timerid) {
            clearTimeout(this.timerid);
          }
          this.timerid = setTimeout(
            () => {
              this.sendMessage();
            },
            300
          );
      }
    }}
    options={options}
    placeholder="Type your queries here..."
    renderMenu={(results, menuProps) => {
      // Hide the menu when there are no results.
      if (!results.length) {
        return null;
      }
      return <TypeaheadMenu {...menuProps} options={results} />;
    }}
  />
  <button onClick={() => this.sendMessage() }>Send</button>
```

This way, I'm calling `sendMessage` method `onKeyDown` and on button click. I'm also able to make use of the selected option object.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely calling `this.form.submit()`, which handles the form submission in the DOM (instead of React), and as you say, takes it out of your control. It's refreshing the page because you don't have control over the event to call `event.preventDefault()`.

Instead of `this.form.submit`, you should call `this.sendMessage` when the user presses enter. Presumably you're calling `event.preventDefault` in `sendMessage`, so you should pass the event through from `onKeyDown`:

```
onKeyDown={e => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    this.sendMessage(e);
  }
}}
```

This way, you will be handling form submission the same whether in response to the user pressing the submit button or enter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I implemented this answer with a slight modification, which meets my project requirement. I will share that here after a full day testing with actual data.